# icacls and removing accidently added permission?

Tags: windows, icacls

I ran command:

```
icacls . /grant domain\joe1:(RX)
```

But I intended to actually run:

```
icacls /grant domain\joe1:(OI)(CI)(M)
```

I went and ran the icacls /grant domain\joe1:(OI)(CI)(M)

Now I a see both when I run

```
icacls .

domain\joe1:(RX)
domain\joe1:(OI)(CI)(M)
```

I tried

```
icacls /remove domain\joe1:(RX)
```

But I cannot get it to remove the RX listed permission

There are many users already with permissions on this folder, so I am trying to avoid a reset on the folder.  How do I remove the RX permission so it just shows the permissions I want?

Comment: Note that for /remove, I tried /remove:g as well.  If I go back one folder, it just shows RX, not the modify.  It does not appear to be an inheritance issue.

Comment: There's `grant:r` to replace an explicit entry, but it appears to require the same flags, so it will add a new entry if we try to replace `(RX)` with `(OI)(CI)(M)`. It seem we have to remove all entries set explicitly for the user via `/remove username`. Then add the correct entry.

Comment: /remove:r and /remove user did not work.  It is like it is waiting for an apply button click in a way.

Comment: `icacls filename /remove username` should work. Some of your examples here are missing the filename in the command, so I don't know what you're running.

Comment: It is just period (.)

Comment: For example, icacls . /remove domain\joe1:(RX).  I also tried icacls *.* /remove domain\joe1:(RX) and did this with /T as well.  Nothing works.  The only way I got it to go was to use the windows gui or use powershell instead.  The behavior of the icacls seems to be like it is waiting for the Apply button to get pressed, but you cannot do that with icacls at least as far as I know.

Comment: Use `icacls . /remove domain\joe1`. It doesn't support removing just the RX entry. All explicit entries for the user have to be removed.

Comment: icacls . /remove domain\joe1 was something I had done.  It did not work.